# One Physical Machine hosting Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 and Thin Client connected to VM Server

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012-r2, hyper-v, thin-client

I apologize if there is already answers to this question.  I looked for hours but was unable to find a solution through multiple trials and errors of possible solutions online.

## Configuration

*ONE* Physical Machine that has Windows 10 on it 
*TWO* Virtual Machines within that one Physical Machines 
Virtual Machine One: Windows Server 2012 R2 
Virtual Machine Two: Thin Client

#### IP Stuff

Physical Machine: Auto-Assigned DHCP Address
VM Server 2012 R2: 192.168.0.104 (This is to be the server)
VM Thin Client: 
Virtual Switch: Internal

## Question

Have the Server VM host a server that the Thin Client would be able to connect to, for testing things such as ADFS, DHCP, DNS, etc., that are being hosted from the Server VM.  (I have tried multiple vSwitch configurations with no success.  I have tried a combination of Internal, External, and Private virtual switches but none of which would allow the vm client connect to the vm server).

Would I need multiple virtual switches?  Is this even possible?

TL;DR  IP Configuration/Virtual Switch setup that would allow a Server in a VM be the domain to a Client in a VM *both on the same physical machine*

Any insight into the matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Karatetoes.......does my answer help at all? if you want the VM to be able to communicate with the Host use an Internal Virtual switch, if you want the VMs to connect to you datacentre use an External virtual switch.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your two virtual machines to be able to communicate with each other all you need to do is configure a Virtual switch in through HyperV Manager, I suggest either a Private virtual switch or an Internal virtual switch. then connect the network adaptor of each VM to the same switch. As long as IP settings match i.e they are on the same network with their own host address, the two VMs should be able to communicate with each other. I use this configuration all the time for testing and development.

If the two VMs cant communicate with each other then there is probably something wrong with the OS configuration in the VMs themselves.